# AWS Pinpoint Endpoints IDs lookup

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I'm experimenting with AWS Pinpoint to send Push Notifications. Apart from anything that AWS front end has to offer I want to be able to send Push Notifications programatically from my Java web app. Those are meant to be single notifications to specific devices and I don't want to use Pinpoint campaigns.

My understanding is that to be able to send a single Push I need an Endpoint ID. My issue is that I can't find a way for my web app to be able to look for an Endpoint ID in the AWS cloud based on, say, user ID. Does anybody thinks there is a way?

Thanks!
Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to target endpoints (devices) based on userId:

1. Set the UserId on the Endpoint [1]
2. Use the Send User Messages API [2]

[1]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/model/EndpointUser.html

[2]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/AmazonPinpointClient.html#sendUsersMessages-com.amazonaws.services.pinpoint.model.SendUsersMessagesRequest-

Comment: @Cheruvian I see you have experience with aws pinpoint. Could you take a look at the question I am linking below? I will appreciate your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226785/how-do-i-store-aws-pinpoint-messages-to-rds